# Installing "AED" package in R version 3.1.0

Tags: r, package

I am trying to install the `AED` package in my console, but I get this warning:

> install.packages("AED")
>   Warning in install.packages :
>    package ‘AED’ is not available (for R version 3.1.0)

I've been searching for solutions in different forums, but I can't find the proper solution. Could anyone help me with this basic problem, please?

Comment: There is no package `AED` available on CRAN. In 30 seconds, I found this [page](http://www.highstat.com/book2.htm).

Answer (score 1):

This package has been discontinued, but in the official book page (Zuur et al 2009), the authors have a link to download all the databases that were in AED.

Look at:

http://www.highstat.com/book2.htm

Answer (score 0):

You may not get the AED package installed.
But see https://rdrr.io/github/romunov/AED/
and apply the following commands:

```
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("romunov/AED")
```

Unfortunately, it did not work for me.

Aternatively, you can:

1. Download all datasets and codes for each chapter of the book 'Mixed Effects Models and Extensions in Ecology with R' from:
   https://www.highstat.com/index.php/books2?view=article&id=16&catid=18
2. Unzip the folder and open the R file 'Chapter#.r'
3. Before using the script, set the corresponding working directory by indicating the appropriate path, for example:

```
setwd("C:/Users/Mora/Downloads/RChapter5/RChapter5")
```

Now, you can access the datasets and run all functions for the corresponding chapter.